# Как сделать кнопками фигуры внутри SVG с (jquery) под сенсорный экран?

Tags: jquery, svg, touch-event

делаю сайт с активными элементами в SVG с выбором объектов под сенсорный экран.

[//билеты-в-цирк.рф/product/view/453/2138.html](http://%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84/product/view/453/2138.html) для просмотра СХЕМА ЗАЛА

```js
 
jQuery('circle').on('click tap', function(){alert('Тап работает!');});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<svg>
    <circle cy=22 cx=66 r= 20></circle>  
    <circle cy=66 cx=22 r= 20></circle>  
</svg>
```

Нужно чтобы элементы Circle в SVG выполняли роль сенсорных кнопок. Чтобы по ним можно было на сенсорном экране тыкать, и чтобы выполнялась своя логика

Comment: Баг: При наведение на "2018 Декабрь" вылезает меню от "Билеты в цирк Никулина:", а должен календарь, как я полагаю.

Comment: Ещё баг: В самом низу где "Дизайн и разработка ExplorerOffice", при нажатие на ссылку выбивает 404ую страницу.. А должна быть ссылка на сайт, да?)

Answer (score 1):

*Как вариант*

Попробуйте добавить код svg инлайн, а анимацию реализовать непосредственно в svg

```html
<svg width="500" height="350">
<circle id="orangeCircle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" >
<animate 
       attributeName="cx"
       from="50"
       to="450" 
       dur="5s"
       begin="click"
       fill="freeze" 
       />
</circle>
<circle id="blueCircle" r="30" cx="50" cy="150" fill="dodgerblue" >

<animate 
       attributeName="cx" 
       from="50"
       to="425" 
       dur="5s"
       begin="click"
       fill="freeze" 
       />
      </circle> 

</svg>
```